# How to download jar file?

Tags: eclipse, jar

I guess this might be a quiet stupid question but this is the first time I want to bring an external jar file ile to Eclipse and I just don´t know how to download it. I want to import: "nl.flotsam.xeger.Xeger"

I found this link but I don´t understand how to download it.. https://code.google.com/p/xeger/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/nl/flotsam/xeger/Xeger.java?r=4

Comment: The jar in the 'Downloads' tab of the bar doesn't have what you want?

Comment: well yeah .. I thought this might be a stupid question but this is really all I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project folder in eclipse -> build path -> configure build path.
Select "Library" tab, click on "Add External Jars" button and select your jar